# Authorisations to invite users via database triggers

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, authorization

Given the following schema:

```
Table "public.users"
        Column        |           Type           |                         Modifiers
----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 uuid                 | uuid                     | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 email                | character varying(254)   | not null
 name                 | text                     | not null
 created_at           | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()

Table "public.users_projects"
     Column      |           Type           |                 Modifiers
-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 project_uuid    | uuid                     | not null
 user_uuid       | uuid                     | not null
 invitation_uuid | uuid                     |
 membership_type | membership_type          | not null default 'member'::membership_type
 created_at      | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()

Table "public.projects"
   Column   |           Type           |              Modifiers
------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------
 uuid       | uuid                     | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 name       | character varying(100)   | not null
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()

Table "public.invitations"
     Column      |           Type           |                 Modifiers
-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 uuid            | uuid                     | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 email           | character varying(254)   | not null
 target_type     | character varying(50)    | not null
 target_uuid     | uuid                     | not null
 membership_type | membership_type          | not null default 'member'::membership_type
 token           | character varying(32)    | not null default md5((random())::text)
 creator_uuid    | uuid                     | not null
```

There is also an enum type `CREATE TYPE membership_type AS ENUM ('guest', 'member', 'manager', 'owner');`.

I'm wondering if I can use triggers to verify that a user cannot create an invitation to a resource, without having at least the `manager` membership type on the join table.

My main questions are:

- Can I use a trigger "before" the row is inserted, `CREATE TRIGGER check_authorisation BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON invitations FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_authorisation();`
- How much information can I give back in an error message, as against just failing because the database connection is down, etc
- Is this a sane approach? As a web application developer, I'm used to an environment where this would be checked in application code, but I'm working on a database that will be shared by two applications (Golang and Ruby)
- Can I implement a `REFERENCES` on the polymorphic fields (`target_type`, `target_uuid`) somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use a trigger "before" the row is inserted, CREATE TRIGGER check_authorisation BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON invitations FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_authorisation();

Make it a (after) constraint trigger, and raise an exception when appropriate.

More generally, use before triggers to modify the incoming data when needed, after triggers to propagate side effects and constraint triggers to validate integrity.

> How much information can I give back in an error message, as against just failing because the database connection is down, etc

As much as you want to send when raising your exception.

> Is this a sane approach? As a web application developer, I'm used to an environment where this would be checked in application code, but I'm working on a database that will be shared by two applications (Golang and Ruby)

It can be sane if done right, but imho it's essentially impossible to properly manage all of the weirder cases that creep in when it comes to authorizations, so this type of logic is usually better located outside of the database.

Case in point: what happens when the manager's secretary's replacement (the original one is on maternity leave) does this?

> Can I implement a REFERENCES on the polymorphic fields (target_type, target_uuid) somehow?

You can, with an after trigger. But depending on what you're doing, consider normalizing this with separate fields, foreign keys, and a check constraint to make sure they're mutually exclusive. It's often easier/cleaner to manage than what will ultimately amount to manually rewriting the foreign key logic.